# Your first In-App Purchase(s) must be submitted with a new app version. Select them from the In-App Purchases section

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I recently developed an iOS app which has in-app purchase enabled.

After completion, I submitted to iTunnesConnect for review, and late on the application is ready for sale.

However, after downloading the app from AppStore, I found in-app purchase is not working. The erason is the in_app purchase is not appear in AppStore at all.

I log into iTunnesConnect and find the In-App-Purchase status is Red with message "Waiting for screenshot to review"

Then I submitted the screenshot and the status for InAppPurchase becomes Amber with status "Ready to Submit"

What I suppose to submit? The app is already alive in AppStore.

The message iTunesConnect give to me is
"Your first In-App Purchase(s) must be submitted with a new app version. Select them from the In-App Purchases section of the Version Details page and then click Ready to Upload Binary."

But the "Submit for Review" button is grey, not clickable.

I did some research and people are saying "Eject the app and submit again", which is not my case. My App is alive already, no option to eject.

Please advice.

Thank you.
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Create an updated version of your app in itunes connect. Rebuild and reupload your binary, even if you don't change anything. You will need to change your build number to resubmit the same binary. After this, go to your in app purchases page and you should be able to click submit for review. Then submit the whole app for review again, and they will approve your in app purchases when they review the whole app.

Comment: my case is same but for new version i add inapp Purchase  and i change its version but not getting the Inapp products in my app ...what is the solution for getting inApp products ..or i submit new version in this situation ??Please help